# Launch program with arguments usually in shortcut target

Tags: c#, command-line, process, arguments

I would like to start a process by providing it *arguments* (not really sure these can be called "arguments"... see below). Now this is a little special:

- The process is a GUI (a game - Call of Duty 4 Multiplayer),
- I have a Windows shortcut to this GUI with the following target : `"C:\\Path To Game\\game.exe" + connect [serverip]` (Note the `+`). When I launch this shortcut, the GUI starts and executes the *arguments* `connect [serverip]` (the game actually starts and connects to the server).

I tried the following:

1. `Process.Start("C:\\Path To Game\\game.exe + connect [serverip]");`

   but this obviously end with an *Win32Exception* "The system cannot find the file specified".
2. ```
   var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
   psi.FileName = "C:\\Path To Game\\game.exe";
   psi.Arguments = "+ connect [serverip]";
   Process.Start(psi);
   ```

   and this produce an error in the GUI (the game doesn't start and says "WIN_IMPROPER_QUIT_BODY").

Any ideas how to provide these *arguments* to my process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you need to set the `WorkingDirectory` for the game

```
string exePath = "C:\\Path To Game\\game.exe";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = exePath;
psi.Arguments = "+ connect [serverip]";
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is the way to go there but what happened to your '+'? It's not a special character, that was just getting passed through to the command, so you need to include it at the start of psi.Arguments too.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in my question (edited now). I tried with the `+`, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
psi.Arguments = "+connect [serverip]";
```

(no space between `+` and `connect`).

Comment: Doesn't work either, but thanks ([@sa_ddam213](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397275/825024) solution works).